# How to render window xaml in C# without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to run and display XAML GUI from the command prompt.

The steps I follow is write the CS code and compile it through the command line but I end up with errors dealing with `InitializeComponent`  about it not being in the context even know I have window `system.window.form` in it and that's not enough appositely, or really anything to do with the GUI components.

The code below is just many I copy and pasted that just errors out. I don't have Visual Studio. I didn't need it to compile my CS code, window comes with the `csc.exe` command to compile c# code. My question revolving around XAML being used, does it come with C# in Windows or is that something totally separate? Doesn't Windows also come with the XAML and form GUI out the box?

No other questions come close to my questions. But you can find out many answer where it shows that Windows comes with C# compiler on Stack Exchange. Please don't point out Visual Studio.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "Change Prperties Through Coding";
            this.BackColor = Color.Brown;
            this.Size = new Size(350, 125);
            this.Location = new Point(300, 300);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

In reply to possible duplicates, it was pointed out that Windows does come with it own C# compiler, but that isn't related to my question.

Comment: Your example is Windows Forms not WPF.   XAML is for WPF... In WPF your window will usually inherit from Window,  InitializeComponent is usually a function generated by VisuaStudio on a separate hidden or designer generated file.  I do not see that function exists in your example; you call it but where is it defined?  I think you need to start by reading a couple of books on C#, WPF, Windows Forms

Comment: @Darkonekt what are you talking about? Listening here, xaml, wpf, uwp, or what else it call or the variations of it i just want to render it. you pointing out visual studio, you act like i didn't do my own search before posting here. you think i like taking this risk of losing the right to ask questions here? There's a tone to learn about xaml the elements and ways to to work with it but what i can't find is how to access it or where to download it or does window comes with it. If you a mod on here delete this questions or give a answer not a suggestion.

Comment: You are mixing things up.... and no you have not done proper research... Yo want to compile xaml yet you show an example of Windows Forms.... Then you do not want to talk about visual studio but obviously you copy that code from an example meant for Visual Studio.... The call to InitializeComponent tells me you did not do your research... because InitializeComponent is NOT part of the Form class it is generated by VISUAL STUDIO!   So you ask about xaml but show windows form code? You say dont talk about visual studio but you show visual studio code.....?

Comment: And to answer your question Windows Forms, WPF are part of the .NET Framework.  And windows comes with it.  Depending on the version of Windows you install you will get a different version of .NET.  You can download and install newer versions of .NET if you want.  That is where all those libraries are..They are part of .NET

Comment: @L2L2L: votes are anonymous here by design, so you have no idea who voted. It is not a good idea to make public guesses as to who voted in what way. Please do not vandalise your posts or add meta-complaints to them. The advice from Darkonect might be rather brusque, but it sounds like he/she knows what they are talking about - if your example is not XAML and yet you want to use XAML, then may we see a minimal example that the console compiler cannot cope with?

Comment: It is not allowed to drastically change your question after you have received an answer. You are welcome to make *clarifications*, even those explaining why the answer does not apply, but your last revision was unacceptable because it transformed the question into something completely different. Furthermore, do not edit in meta-commentary about votes, deletion, etc. That does not belong in the question. Any content posted to this site becomes licensed under CC BY-SA, granting Stack Overflow the perpetual right to display it as they wish, provided that they attribute it to you.

Comment: what answer that answer just restated what i said in my last revision! And with these down vote which probably you added i need to go send another request to have this deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that you can build C# and other .NET code without Visual Studio. `csc.exe` is the Microsoft C# Compiler and it can be used for this. On my computer, csc.exe is located here:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Your computer might have it in a different folder.

As for the code, if that's the only file you have, you'll end up with a few errors.

- There's no entry point. Usually this is in Program.cs.
- Your class relies on System.Windows.Forms. However, you need some way of adding a reference. Normally this is done through a project file. It's also possible to add the reference directly when calling csc. However, that becomes cumbersome after more than a few references.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't even look to be present in the first place. Error for example trying to use `InitializeComponent` will result in a "does not exist in context". So it make me thinks that c# don't come with this feature out the box. But window does include cpc compiler out the box. so I guess one answer would be from someone who can say "no it doesn't come out the box with xaml you have to download that" and give me a link to download that. And down vote effect me very much as the user so one more down vote and i'm delete my post so i don't be effected badly by it.

Comment: @L2L2L: please edit that error information into your question, that might be useful for readers in general. If there is a stack trace to go along with that, please add that too.

Comment: Hey @DougJohnson (@Doug Johnson) you spoke of adding reference with csc. Care to show some example of this? Both on where to get System.Windows.Forms and how to add it as a reference to use as a build tool. To say it becomes cumbersome is to look down on pass wizards who use this as their only method, relying on tools such as visual studio can weaken one too... I rather rely on Microsoft tool as less as possible beside the os. Anyway if you can add on to your answer of what i request, it'll be a help to me and maybe others.

Comment: Sure, you can reference DLLs from csc.exe using the /r switch.
If you need to reference multiple DLLS, separate them with a semicolon.
Here's an example:
csc.exe Program.cs /r:System.Windows.Forms.dll

Answer (score 0):

partially you can't with out visual studio or visual studio community version. WPF is being added to .net core but i don't know would that mean will it still fully need visual studio. All information that speak of xaml, wpf, uwp, or any other variations of this tool speak in using visual studio to render it. This tool is a gui framework use in window application that has advance the still in use but old framework called WinForms.